# Odd rendering issue when navigating between tabs with a DrawerNavigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a basic tabbed phone application that I'm building in React Native, with one of the tabs containing a DrawerNavigator. The basic structure looks like:

```
createBottomTabNavigator ->

    DrawerNavigator ->
        DashboardStack
        Test

    Survey ->
        SurveyStack

    Settings ->
        SettingsStack
```

This all builds, works, and looks great, but I'm seeing an odd rendering lifecycle bug. If I use the drawer navigator to open of of its children (say, "Survey") and then click on one of the other options in the Bottom Tab navigator within about 1 second, the screen flashes briefly and takes me back to the screen within the DrawerNavigator. The screens in the DrawerNavigator aren't all that rich, but I'm guessing that this is still related to the screen continuing to build and re-draw while I am trying to navigate away with the tabs. I realize that this is a difficult thing to describe without actually seeing the behavior on the phone, but if anyone has suggestions as to how I might solve this or which lifecycle methods I should be looking at, I'd really appreciate it. Here's the way we currently have the tab navigator set up:

```
const AboutUsStack = createStackNavigator({
    AboutUs: AboutUsScreen
});

const TestStack = createStackNavigator({
    Test: TestScreen
});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Message : MessageScreen,
  About : AboutUsScreen,
});


const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Dashboard: HomeStack,
        AboutUs : AboutUsStack,
        Test : TestStack
    },
    {
        navigationOptions :  {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                <TabBarIcon
                    focused={focused}
                    name="ios-home"
                />
            )
        }

    }

);


const SurveyStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Surveys: SurveyScreen
    },
    {
        navigationOptions : {
        tabBarLabel: 'Survey',
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon
                focused={focused}
                name="ios-document"
            />
        )
        }
    }

);




const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Settings: SettingsScreen
    },
    {
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarLabel: 'Account',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                <TabBarIcon
                    focused={focused}
                    name="ios-settings"
                />
            ),
        }
    }

);


export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  DrawerNavigator,
  SurveyStack,
  SettingsStack
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for putting the drawer navigator on the tab?

Comment: We have some content within that tab that is all related, but we still want our users to be able to jump over to other tabs at any point.